# Controlling WPF in native interop

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, .net-4.0

I'm writing an application in native code and wish to use WPF for a user-interface library. Now, I've got the interoperation down relatively easily, but ultimately, I'm trying to write a native app, with WPF as a library, not a WPF app with a few native extensions. That said, I'm looking for an interoperation solution with certain qualities that I just can't seem to find in any examples.

Firstly, I definitely want to write my own main loop. I might perform arbitrary actions in native code and I want the ability to poll, for example, in each iteration. My application is definitely not a "sleep until you click something" application.

Secondly, I want the ability to control WPF. I want to say when WPF processes input. I want to say when it renders. I want it to make me a sammich, when I say so. This is one of the bigger problems that I have. Surely these methods must exist inside WPF, they're just not exposed anywhere that I can find them.

I've been looking into CLR hosting, but it doesn't seem to have a kind of, "Go until finished" thing that I'm looking for. Even if I cracked open a critical section or something, even from managed code there's no way to make WPF do what you want.

Comment: Have you considered putting your WPF GUI in a winform control and using the latest as an ActiveX control?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you want to write your own main loop/message pump for WPF. I remember reading about this in a message thread a while back. It's not a full answer, but I wonder if it might point you in the right direction.

> Subject: Game loops in WPF? 
>   wondering how easy it would be to write a custom "game loop" within the WPF framework. By game loop, I mean pumping my own events on a custom Dispatcher so I can control the framerate of my app.
>
> Answer: 
>   You can write your own message pump. Just don't call Dispatcher.Run. You need to pump messages, and you need to call ComponentDispatcher.RaiseThreadMessage as appropriate. Use reflector to see what Dispatcher.PushFrame does.
>
> Of course, this still may not give you what you want for a "game loop"...

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/06/29/wpf-discussions-090626.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look at [HwndSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.aspx). It hosts a WPF GUI as a win32 control. Its all a bit tricky though and you're probably better off writing a plain WPF .net GUI app and using it to drive your native code using some form of interop. MS really didn't think of this kind of migration approach (reusing your existing code and slapping a new GUI on top) preferring to make us all rewrite all our code.

There are plenty of examples around the web. Good luck.

PS.
of course you could try the current 'gold standard' in native GUIs - [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/).